# Bootstrap web page shaking when cursor moveover on hyperlink button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made web application using by Bootstrap and Cakephp. One of the master - list screen, Every row has a action edit/delete hyperlink buttons. When i cursor move on the hyperlink edit/delete buttons with bootstrap classes (btn-primary, btn-danger), the web page has automatically shake all the time. I guess issue in the btn a:hover classes. Anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: is that 'shaking' becoming due to occurence and  absence of scroll bar?

Comment: Share the code as well

Comment: My guess it's padding / margin being appended on hover state, which gives the impression it's 'shaking'